Making Document Entity Destination Non Safe-Ordered in PolicyCenter
I have a destination configured in the messaging-config.xml file that listens to document entities, specifically document creation events, in PolicyCenter. This destination is  set as safe-ordered at the account level by default. We want to change this configuration so that all documents are sent without considering the account, making the destination non safe-ordered. As I understand it, in PolicyCenter, the default safe ordering is at the account level, and the only alternate primary entity option available is Contact. Is there a way to configure this destination as non safe-ordered?

Yes, you can do this, but be careful and do it knowing that you're not getting safe ordering for anything using this event fired rule. To achieve this, you simply null out all of the possible primary objects for this message. In PolicyCenter, this is Account and Contact. So add these two lines to your event fired rule, as in the example below:
message.Account = null
message.Contact = null
package rules.EventMessage.EventFired_dir

@gw.rules.RuleName("TestRuleSet")
internal class TestRuleSet {
  static function doCondition(messageContext : entity.MessageContext) : boolean {
/*start00rule*/
return true
/*end00rule*/
}

  static function doAction(messageContext : entity.MessageContext, actions : gw.rules.Action) {
/*start00rule*/
    var message = messageContext.createMessage("Test Payload")
    message.Account = null
    message.Contact = null
/*end00rule*/
  }
}


I tried this and it worked as expected. I just wanted to confirm if this is the recommended approach by Guidewire for achieving non-safe ordering, and if it's acceptable to implement this in a production environment?

It would be preferable to call .addEvent() on an entity which is outside of the context of an Account or Contact, possibly a custom entity, and would thus be inherently not safe-ordered. The issue with nulling out these fields is that future developers may not realize that you've applied this workaround and will not understand why other messages being processed by this destination are not delivered in order. This is why I suggested you use this approach with due care and document it well.

In your message destination configuration, you'll see a field called "Message without primary". If you just want to push the data out of InsuranceSuite as quickly as possible without regard for the order, choose "Multi Thread", and then make sure the primary object is null. Messages without a primary object will cut to the front of the line if there are messages with a primary object they're safe ordered around. When you have a primary object, you'll still get safe ordering. Check out this sample code I threw together in ClaimCenter for a demonstration of the behavior. The primary entity around which you can safe order is a bit different in ClaimCenter compared to PolicyCenter, but this demonstrates the concepts which are identical between the two applications.
This code creates a demo message destination which we'll be sending both safe-ordered and non safe-ordered messages on. Since I'm in ClaimCenter, I'm safe ordered by Claim. I'm PolicyCenter, your document objects are safe ordered on Account, unless you've explicitly configured otherwise.
First, create this dummy entity. Note, I've made it event aware. This is crucial. Without the events tag, this won't work.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entity
  xmlns="http://guidewire.com/datamodel"
  entity="TestEntity"
  desc="TestEntity"
  table="testentity"
  type="retireable">

  <events/>
  <column
    name="DummyColumn"
    nullok="true"
    type="longtext"/>
</entity>

Now create a new Message Destination which listens on a custom event, by adding this to messaging-config.xml. Note I'm assigning it 10 sender threads:
<destination
  id="3"
  multithreadnonsafeorderedmessages="true"
  name="TestNotOrdered"
  numsenderthreads="10"
  transportplugin="NotSafeOrderedTransport">
  <event
    name="NotSafeOrderedEvent"/>
</destination>

Add this plugin config to your plugin registry and call it NotSafeOrderedTransport.gwp:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugin
  interface="MessageTransport"
  name="NotSafeOrderedTransport">
  <plugin-gosu
    gosuclass="test.NotSafeOrderedPlugin"/>
</plugin>

Add then add the Gosu implementation of the Transport plugin:
package test

uses gw.plugin.messaging.MessageTransport

class NotSafeOrderedPlugin implements MessageTransport {

  override function send(message : Message, transformedPayload : String) {
    print (Thread.currentThread().Name + " Sending message with messageroot " + message.MessageRoot)
    Thread.sleep(2000); //sleep for 2 seconds to simulate doing something
    print (Thread.currentThread().Name + " Finished sending " + message.MessageRoot)
    message.reportAck()
  }

  override function shutdown() {
  }

  override function suspend() {
  }

  override function resume() {
  }

  override property set DestinationID(destinationID : int) {

  }
}

Now, fire up ClaimCenter in debug mode.  Run this following script in the Gosu Scratchpad, or modify it to use Document instead of Claim in PC. What it does is it will create a bunch of Safe-Ordered, primary entity containing messages, for me ordered on the primary entity of a claim. They will go in order, there's nothing you can do about that. You will see in the logs that it's single threading through the processing of them, because they're all on the same primary entity. Then the code adds a bunch of non-safe ordered events based on our new custom entity. Since their primary entity is null, they'll immediately jump to the front of the queue, skipping all the Claim-based entities. You'll see this in the console output: all of the processing of the safe ordered messages stops as the non safe ordered jump to the front of the line. Also you'll notice, they are processed out of order. So if you want to push your Document based messages out of order, you'll need to null out the primary entity, or else trigger the event on another entity, and then modify your code to look up the Document.
var claim = Claim.finder.findClaimByClaimNumber("000-00-000003")
gw.transaction.Transaction.runWithNewBundle(\bundle->{
  for (x in 0..100){
    claim = bundle.add(claim)
    claim.addEvent("NotSafeOrderedEvent")
  }
},User.util.getUnrestrictedUser())

Thread.sleep (10000) //sleep for 10 seconds and watch how ClaimCenter processes these claims in order

//now add 100 of these nonsafe ordered entity-based messages, and see how we're fully utilizing all configured threads
//and processing them far faster
gw.transaction.Transaction.runWithNewBundle(\bundle->{
  for (x in 0..100){
    var session = bundle.add(new TestEntity())
    session.DummyColumn = "dummy"
    session.addEvent("NotSafeOrderedEvent")
  }
},User.util.getUnrestrictedUser())


We have a similar requirement with an additional scenario to consider. For example, let's take documents in ClaimCenter with a destination set to "10," specifically looking at the DocumentCreate event. Suppose we have a claim, say claim1, and for this claim, five documents are generated. If the first document fails at the transport layer due to some error, the payloads of the remaining four documents get stuck in the transport layer. These other documents will not be sent until the first one is either successfully sent or skipped.

We are trying to avoid this situation by making sure that all document events are non-safe ordered, allowing the other documents to attempt sending even if the first one is stuck. Could you please help us achieve this? I'm also wondering if we can set the primary object to null in this case or if there's another approach we can take.
